# Brand new HDD is still processing something after copying huge amount of files onto it?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, storage, usb-storage, noise

I put a brand new HDD into an external HDD enclosure. After copying a huge amount of data onto this drive, the disk head is still processing something even two hours later (the copying process has already finished, but it sounds like the drive is "putting things in place").

Is that a normal behavior?

It does not sound like a defect or anything else, it sounds more like I would still copy things on it and therefore the head moves around. When unmounting the drive those sounds will stop and the drive will still spin, but stop moving the head.

Maybe the OS is adjusting something?

Comment: Windows? Indexing.

Comment: Be sure system restore is disabled for that drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External disk still being active two hours later is abnormal and should be investigated.
It could be indexing or antivirus, but two hours is a bit long.

I suggest to download and install the free
[Sysinternals Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

In Process Explorer, click the binoculars icon and search for `X:`, where `X` is
the drive-letter of the disk. This will tell you which processes have opened files
on the disk and might help to identify them.

If the name of the process is `svchost`, this is a system service.
Double-click it twice, once in the search dialog and once in the process list,
and check the Services tab to see which service(s) it is.

If Process Explorer can find no processes that are accessing the disk,
this is then the disk's firmware that is doing its first-time setup.
Let it go on for a couple of days.
But if it still keeps on going, then something is wrong, and I would counsel
to have the disk replaced if under warranty.

Comment: Excellent piece of software, highly recommended if you want an insight on what's going on in your Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It could be any number of things. It could be doing g a virus scan or indexing the drive for searching. You might have a program running in the background that searches new drives for media files. Etc, etc. If the copying said it's finished, it should be finished. If you want to remove the drive from the system, properly eject it from the system and you should be good to go.